# calling google cloud functions from java spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google cloud functions with no problem in my mobile app using specific sdk for iOS and swift. For integrations reason I would now need to call one of my functions from a java springboot server.

I cannot find any example for that,  does a specific client and example exist ?

I can find examples for other platform but not for java. Am I missing something ? can someone move me in the right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your functions is private? (I mean you have to be authenticated for calling it?)

Comment: yes it is private and need to be authenticated

Comment: How do you want your clients to authenticate? With google accounts or something else? If you can access your server you may be interested in using HTTP requests that trigger the function and adding the identity token in the header.

Comment: I was reading about that. actually ,  in android ,  I'm using the sdk.  You have to dowload the json for authentication then you got all needed functions.  I was wondering if there's something similar for java .  Looking at google do it's not always easy

Comment: Is it service to service authentication? Do you have a service account key or your spring boot app run on GCP? Is an Android call?

Comment: Hello,  the application is a java application running on GCP on a VM instance. I'm already connected to firebase using the sdk and the json file used for authentication. looks like I need a different sdk for java and cloud functions (but I could be wrong) .   I ALSO have an android app (java written) where I have the andoird java sdk and the support for the cloud functions . everything is ok there.  My problem is how to call the functions from inside the java application on the VM instance. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do HTTP requests, that will trigger the cloud functions. [Here is the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http)

Comment: it need to be authenticated ,  from android ( still java) there's a specific client for that

Answer (score 0):

GCP has [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) regarding the authentication on Cloud Functions. Since you need to authenticate on a Cloud Function from a VM inside your GCP project, I recommend you to read [this section](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers).

As explained, you should get an Identity Token that can authenticate on Cloud Functions. You can fetch the token either from [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token) or the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#identity_tokens). After you have that in whatever format you can access it without compromising your credentials (e.g. environment variable, file outside the repository) just perform the HTTP request to the trigger of the function.

In the end you should have something like this:

```
cf_trigger = "https://<region>-<project_id>.cloudfunctions.net/<function_name>"
identity_token = "foo"

HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(cf_trigger))
    .header("Authorization", "bearer " + identity_token)
    .build();
```